# What is the throw statement?

Tags: java, grammar, throw

I know that I must pass one single argument: a throwable object. But I really don’t know what kind
of keyword is `throw`.

It is not a Class, because we don’t pass the throwable object as constructor parameter, nor is an annotation, because `throw`is not preceded by the @ character. And so on.

So, what is exactly the throw statement?

Thanks!

Comment: [Google it](https://www.google.com/search?q=What+is+the+throw+statement%3F&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:he:official&client=firefox-a&channel=sb)

Comment: It's a keyword, just like `if` or `return`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a reserved keyword, see [section 3.9](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.9) of the [Java Language Specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/index.html).

Answer (score 1):

`throw` is used to activate an Exception.

`throw new Exception("This is an exception");`

You can also use Inheritance and make your own type of Exceptions and throw and handle them.

Answer (score 1):

throw is a regular java keyword, which is used to "throw" an <strike>exception</strike>Throwable object.
in my opinion, **throw** is not more *magic* or *mysterious* than **break** or **continue**....